# supervisor crashes hue /etc/init.d/hue status

Tags: hadoop, process, cloudera, hue

I am using CLoudera Quickstart VM in VMWare, the trial single node version.
So far Hue has been working great but now on Firefox if i go on Hue it says Unable to connect
EDIT:
supervisor keeps stopping, if i do

```
sudo /etc/init.d/hue status
```

returns supervisor is stopped

```
sudo /etc/init.d/hue start
```

it is running but in few seconds

```
sudo /etc/init.d/hue status
```

returns that supervisor is stopped again. 
Why? i checked the logs in /var/log/hue/supervisor.log

and it goes

```
[14/Jan/2015 23:55:07 ] supervisor   WARNING  Supervisor shutting down!
[14/Jan/2015 23:55:07 ] supervisor   WARNING  Waiting for children to exit for 5 seconds...
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:19 ] supervisor   INFO     Starting process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:19 ] supervisor   INFO     Starting process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:20 ] supervisor   INFO     Started proceses (pid 3070) /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:20 ] supervisor   INFO     Started proceses (pid 3071) /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:22 ] supervisor   WARNING  Exit code for /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver: 1
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:22 ] supervisor   ERROR    Process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver exited abnormally. Restarting it.
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:22 ] supervisor   INFO     Starting process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:22 ] supervisor   INFO     Started proceses (pid 3090) /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:22 ] supervisor   WARNING  Exit code for /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer: 1
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:22 ] supervisor   ERROR    Process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer exited abnormally. Restarting it.
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:22 ] supervisor   INFO     Starting process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:22 ] supervisor   INFO     Started proceses (pid 3091) /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:24 ] supervisor   WARNING  Exit code for /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer: 1
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:24 ] supervisor   ERROR    Process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer exited abnormally. Restarting it.
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:24 ] supervisor   INFO     Starting process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:24 ] supervisor   INFO     Started proceses (pid 3106) /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:24 ] supervisor   WARNING  Exit code for /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver: 1
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:24 ] supervisor   ERROR    Process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver exited abnormally. Restarting it.
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:24 ] supervisor   INFO     Starting process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:24 ] supervisor   INFO     Started proceses (pid 3107) /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:26 ] supervisor   WARNING  Exit code for /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer: 1
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:26 ] supervisor   ERROR    Process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer exited abnormally. Restarting it.
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:26 ] supervisor   INFO     Starting process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:26 ] supervisor   INFO     Started proceses (pid 3124) /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:26 ] supervisor   WARNING  Exit code for /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver: 1
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:26 ] supervisor   ERROR    Process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver exited abnormally. Restarting it.
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:26 ] supervisor   INFO     Starting process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:26 ] supervisor   INFO     Started proceses (pid 3125) /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:28 ] supervisor   WARNING  Exit code for /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer: 1
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:28 ] supervisor   ERROR    Process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer has restarted more than 3 times in the last 6 seconds
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:28 ] supervisor   WARNING  Exit code for /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver: 1
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:28 ] supervisor   ERROR    Process /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver has restarted more than 3 times in the last 6 seconds
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:29 ] supervisor   WARNING  Supervisor shutting down!
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:29 ] supervisor   WARNING  Waiting for children to exit for 5 seconds...
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:29 ] supervisor   ERROR    Exception in supervisor main loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/supervisor.py", line 386, in main
    wait_loop(sups, options)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/supervisor.py", line 403, in wait_loop
    shutdown(sups)        # shutdown() exits the process
  File "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/supervisor.py", line 215, in shutdown
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
[15/Jan/2015 00:02:29 ] supervisor   WARNING  Supervisor shutting down!
```

what is happening?

OLD QUESTION:
    Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at quickstart.cloudera:8888.

Any idea why?

I upgraded to java 1.7 because of cassandra, can it be the reason? If so, how to fix this?

so i checked if the port was blocked but if I do `# netstat -tulpn` inside the VM
[blabla]
therefore it should not be taken right? (since it is not in the rightmost column)

Comment: This issue not related to Java because you are not trying to connect via java program. Check whether this URL or port accessible in outside of VM . If you are able to access, then check with VM network

Comment: i am sorry, i am really ignorant about the field, how do you check that? isn't it the localhost?

Comment: Did you check if Hue was up and running in Cloudera Manager (quickstart.cloudera:7180)?

Comment: @Romain i did sudo /home/cloudera/cloudera-manager --force it succedeed after a few mins and now at     http://quickstart.cloudera:7180 i get the same message
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at quickstart.cloudera:7180. Why??

Comment: I mean if you login on quickstart.cloudera:7180, then check if the Hue service is healthy?

Comment: Please check the completely edited question. As i said it is not, it crashed and is not staying up anymore, no idea why. I downloaded another VM because I was not able to get where the issue was, if you have any ideas I am definitively curious.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Any solution yet?

Comment: As i said I changed the machine since I couldn't find the issue, therefore cannot help on this. If you come up with a solution of some sort please let us know.